# Ajax com Python - Quero chamar função que está em default

Tags: mysql, ajax, python

Estou querendo fazer uma validação no Banco MySQL através de Ajax.
Criei uma função chamada *validaCNPJ()* que está no controller chamado *Default*.

Porém não sei como coloco esta função nos parametros do Ajax.
Alguém consegue me dar o caminho das pedras?

Este é meu Script que está na pagina HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("idCnpj").typehead(function(){
         $.ajax({url: "???????? ", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Não está claro qual o framework web você usa mas vamos lá:

Segundo a [documentação da API do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), você pode setar o atributo `method` com o `POST` que fará um `POST` em alguma view sua preparada pra receber esses dados e tratá-los.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

Além do `method`, temos a `url` que é onde o `POST` deve ser feito e o atributo `data` contendo os dados do seu formulário.

A função `done` é o *callback* do AJAX em caso de sucesso.

Caso não tenha ficado claro, sugiro estudar este link do [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp).